# Fuzzy Matching for Duplicate Address Checks

Tags: account, code, data, address

A good duplicate checker - for checking if the same address has already been entered - needs to take into account misspellings or spelling variations.

We have implemented our own APEX methods which transform each address field (name, street, city, postcode) into a phonetic code. These codes are then compared with other addresses to find possible duplicates. A fuzzy probability is assigned based on the type of match.

How are other users here approaching duplicate checks? Anyone employing the new `String.getLevenshteinDistance()`?

I'll post my own code below in the interests of knowledge sharing.

Comment: I feel this is a picture-perfect application of `String.getLevenshteinDistance` if there ever was one. Perhaps you can combine the [progressive exposure of batch apex output using the Streaming API](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/01/responsive-visualforce-using-streaming-api-and-asynchronous-apex.html) with the [distance check on the fields of interest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210980/optimizing-levenshtein-distance-algorithm-in-salesforce)...

Comment: I have created my own question 
my question can be found at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10705/fuzzy-logic-matching-on-company-name-leads

Comment: User 320 Thank you for your posts in reference to this post. In one of your posts you mentioned that this is a perfect example of String.getLevenshteinDistance . I don't want to seem thick but where did you get that from ? Looking at his coding it looks like its only phonetic ! Or am u mis understanding the code ?

Answer (score 4):

#### Phonetic Encoding Algorithm

```
/**
 * Encode a word phonetically
 * 'HeLLLL00 World!'
 *  -> 'HLWRLD'
 *    -> 'H40643'
 *       Which is the same code as 'Hello World!'
 */
public static string phonetic(string ip, integer max) {

    if (ip == null || ip == '') return '';

    string op = ip.toUpperCase();

    // Encode phonetically similar letters as same number
    op = op.replaceAll('[^BFPVCGJKQSXZDTLMNR]', '0');
    op = op.replaceAll('[BFPV]', '1');
    op = op.replaceAll('[CGJKQSXZ]', '2');
    op = op.replaceAll('[DT]', '3');
    op = op.replaceAll('[L]', '4');
    op = op.replaceAll('[MN]', '5');
    op = op.replaceAll('[R]', '6');

    // Remove double-letters
    string op2 = op.substring(0,1);
    for (integer i=1; i<op.length()-1; i++) {
        string c2 = op.substring(i,i+1);
        if (!op2.endsWith(c2)) op2 += c2;
        //system.debug('******'+op2);
    }

    // Limit length of code returned
    if (max > op2.length()) max = op2.length();

    // Keep first letter of original word
    op2 = ip.substring(0,1) + op2.substring(1, max);

    return op2;
}
```

#### Helper Functions

```
// Convert nulls to empty strings
private static string ops(string s) {
    return s == null?'':s;
}
```

#### Find Accounts Matching Address

```
/**
  * Return all accounts matching this address
  *  The field AnnualRevenue is misused to return the probability of match
  */
public static List<Account> AccountsByAddress(String Name1, String Street, String Postcode, String City, String Country) {

    List<Account> result = new List<Account>();

    List<Account> accs;
    Integer MAX = 50;

    // Find accounts with same postcode OR city
    accs = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingPostalCode, BillingCity, BillingCountry
            FROM Account
            WHERE BillingCountry = :Country AND (BillingPostalCode = :Postcode OR BillingCity = :City)
            LIMIT :MAX];
    if (accs.size() == MAX) {
        // Too many, enforce same postcode
        accs = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingPostalCode, BillingCity, BillingCountry
                FROM Account
                WHERE BillingCountry = :Country AND BillingPostalCode = :Postcode
                LIMIT :MAX];
    }
    if (accs.size() == 0) {
        // None, try same city
        system.debug('Fuzzy pre-selected none!');
        accs = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingPostalCode, BillingCity, BillingCountry
            FROM Account
            WHERE BillingCountry = :Country AND BillingCity = :City
            LIMIT :MAX];
    } else if (accs.size() == MAX) {
        // Too many, enforce city
        system.debug('Fuzzy postcode pre-selected too many!');
        accs = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingPostalCode, BillingCity, BillingCountry
                          FROM Account
                          WHERE BillingCountry = :Country AND BillingPostalCode = :Postcode AND BillingCity = :City
                          LIMIT :MAX];
    }
    system.debug('Fuzzy accounts Pre-selected '+accs.size());

    if (accs.size() == MAX) {
        // Too many, enforce name
        system.debug('Fuzzy postcode and city pre-selected too many(2)!');
        string Name4 = Name1.substring(0, 4)+'%';
        accs = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingPostalCode, BillingCity, BillingCountry
                          FROM Account
                          WHERE BillingCountry = :Country AND BillingPostalCode = :Postcode AND BillingCity = :City
                            AND Name LIKE :Name4
                          LIMIT :MAX];
    }
    system.debug('Fuzzy accounts pre-selected '+accs.size());

    String Name10   = phonetic(Name1, 10);
    String Street10 = phonetic(Street, 10);
    String City10   = phonetic(City, 10);
    system.debug('Name10='+Name10+', Street10='+Street10+', City10='+City10);

    String Name4   = phonetic(Name1, 4);
    String Street4 = phonetic(Street, 4);
    String City4   = phonetic(City, 4);
    system.debug('Name4='+Name4+', Street4='+Street4+', City4='+City4);

    for (Account acc: accs) {
        system.debug(acc);
        Boolean SameName     = (acc.Name == Name1);
        // SF Street is multi-line, if SAP Street is in there somewhere it's a match
        Boolean SameStreet   = (acc.BillingStreet == Street || ops(acc.BillingStreet).indexOf(Street)>=0);
        Boolean SameCity     = (acc.BillingCity == City);
        Boolean SamePostcode = (acc.BillingPostalCode == Postcode);
        system.debug('SameName='+SameName+', SameStreet='+SameStreet+', SameCity='+SameCity+', SamePostcode='+SamePostcode);

        Boolean Like10Name   = (phonetic(acc.Name, 10) == Name10);
        Boolean Like10Street = (phonetic(acc.BillingStreet, 10) == Street10);
        Boolean Like10City   = (phonetic(acc.BillingCity, 10) == City10);
        system.debug('Like10Name='+Like10Name+', Like10Street='+Like10Street+', Like10City='+Like10City);

        Boolean Like4Name   = (phonetic(acc.Name, 4) == Name4);
        Boolean Like4Street = (phonetic(acc.BillingStreet, 4) == Street4);
        Boolean Like4City   = (phonetic(acc.BillingCity, 4) == City4);
        system.debug('Like4Name='+Like4Name+', Like4Street='+Like4Street+', Like4City='+Like4City);

        if (SameName && SameStreet && SameCity && SamePostcode)
          acc.AnnualRevenue = 99;
        else if (SameName && SameStreet && SameCity) acc.AnnualRevenue = 98;
        else if (SameName && SameStreet && ( SameCity || SamePostcode )) acc.AnnualRevenue = 97;
        else if (SameName && Like10Street && SameCity && SamePostcode)   acc.AnnualRevenue = 96;
        else if (Like10Name && SameStreet && SameCity)            acc.AnnualRevenue = 95;
        else if (SameName && SameCity && SamePostcode)            acc.AnnualRevenue = 94;
        else if (SameName && SameStreet && Like10City)            acc.AnnualRevenue = 94;
        else if (SameName && Like10Street && Like10City)          acc.AnnualRevenue = 93;
        else if (Like10Name && SameStreet && Like10City)          acc.AnnualRevenue = 92;
        else if (Like10Name && Like10Street && SameCity)          acc.AnnualRevenue = 91;
        else if (Like10Name && Like10Street && Like10City)        acc.AnnualRevenue = 90;
        else if (SameName && Like4Street && SameCity)             acc.AnnualRevenue = 86;
        else if (Like4Name && SameStreet && SameCity)             acc.AnnualRevenue = 85;
        else if (SameName && SameStreet && Like4City)             acc.AnnualRevenue = 84;
        else if (SameName && Like4Street && Like4City)            acc.AnnualRevenue = 83;
        else if (Like4Name && SameStreet && Like4City)            acc.AnnualRevenue = 82;
        else if (Like4Name && Like4Street && SameCity)            acc.AnnualRevenue = 81;
        else if (Like4Name && Like4Street && Like4City)           acc.AnnualRevenue = 80;
        else if (SamePostcode && Like4City && Like10Name && country != 'China' && country != 'Korea' && country != 'Japan')
          // Same postcode, similar city(4), similar name(10)
          acc.AnnualRevenue = 80;
        else if (SameName && SameCity)
          // Different postcode, same name, same city (postcode misspelled)
          acc.AnnualRevenue = 80;
        else if (SameCity && SameStreet)
          // Same postcode, city && street - name might be misspelled
          acc.AnnualRevenue = 79;
        else if (SameName && SameStreet)              acc.AnnualRevenue = 74;
        else if (Like4Name && Like4Street)            acc.AnnualRevenue = 73;
        else if (Like4Street && SameCity)             acc.AnnualRevenue = 72;
        else if (Like4Name && Like4City)              acc.AnnualRevenue = 71;
        else {
          // Probably not a duplicate
          system.debug('PROB=0');
          continue;
        }
        system.debug('PROB='+acc.AnnualRevenue);

        result.add(acc);
    }

    return result;
}
```

#### Use Case

```
// Check account newAcc against all Accounts
Account[] accs = Fuzzy.AccountsByAddress(
                   newAcc.Name,
                   ,newAcc.BillingStreet
                   ,newAcc.BillingPostalCode
                   ,newAcc.BillingCity
                   ,newAcc.BillingCountry
                 );
```

Comment: Hope your well, sorry for messaging you out of the blue, i found your post very informative, however i do have a few questions . Do you have an email address where i can contact you on ? Regards
Daniel

Comment: Just ask the question here, @Masond3 - or ask a new question if it's 'substantial'.